# EntityFieldQuery HAVING clause

Tags: 7, database

Is there any way I can use having clause with EntityFieldQuery? I want to get the nodes which have same field value similar to HAVING clause in SQL. Or do I need to do other ways? Please suggest if there is any good way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`havingCondition`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3ahavingCondition/7) available in the query builder.

```
$query = db_select('node, 'n');

// add fields or other conditions

$query->havingCondition('nid', array(1, 2, 3), 'IN');
```

Comment: [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) doesn't have that method...

Comment: Thank you Mike and Clive. I did it using havingCondition for now.

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass `EntityFieldQuery` and add a `having()` method, or (probably quicker) you can add a tag to the query, and use [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7) to alter it when it's a standard `SelectQuery`:

```
function MYMODULE_query_my_tag_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->having('some_field > :val', array(':val' => $some_val));
}
```

To use that with your query:

```
$query = new \EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->fieldCondition(...)
  ->addTag('my_tag');
```

Comment: There is a havingCondition you could take a look at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AhavingCondition/7 though you would probably still need to do something to expose it.

Comment: @Steven yeah `havingCondition()` is probably better to use than `having()` actually, unless it needs a complex expression. The only ways to expose those methods are to write a subclass of `EntityFieldQuery` which implements them (and alters the underlying query by overriding `EntityFieldQuery::execute()`), or alter the query like the code above. Fortunately it's a very small amount of code